# Possible initialized jagged array error C#

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I am using a Jagged array of GameObjects for tiled map generation, and I keep getting the error:

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
>   (wrapper stelemref) object:stelemref (object,intptr,object)
>   Map.GenerateMap () (at Assets/Scripts/Map.cs:148)
>   Map.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Map.cs:74)

I am completely stumped as to why I am getting this error. Below is the full function I have written with the initialization of the jagged array. As far as I know I am initializing the array correctly.

```
void GenerateMap(){
    mapWidth = Random.Range (5, 25);
    mapHeight = Random.Range (5, 25);

    //Initialise the Jagged Array
    genMapArray = new GameObject [mapHeight][];
    for (int i = 0; i < mapHeight; i++)
        genMapArray [i] = new GameObject [mapWidth];

    //Generate some mountains
    int mountX = Random.Range(1, mapWidth - 1); // Random within 
    int mountY = Random.Range(1, mapHeight - 1); // the map border


    for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight+1; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth+1; x++) {

            if((y == 0 && x <= mapWidth) || (y <= mapHeight & x == 0) ||
                (y== mapHeight && x <= mapWidth) || (y <= mapHeight && x == mapWidth)){
                genMapArray[y][x] = Tiles[0];
            }else{
                if(y == mountY && x == mountX){
                    genMapArray[y][x] = Tiles[3];
                }else{
                    genMapArray[y][x] = Tiles[1];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Draw Tiles on the Screen
    for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight+1; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth+1; x++) {

            if (useSquareTiles == true && useHexagonTiles == false) {
                GameObject.Instantiate (genMapArray[y][x], new Vector3 (x, mapHeight - y, 0),
                                        Quaternion.Euler (-90, 0, 0));
            }

            if (useHexagonTiles == true && useSquareTiles == false) {
                float hexWidth = 0.75f / Mathf.Cos (Mathf.Deg2Rad * 30.0f); 
                GameObject.Instantiate (genMapArray[y][x], new Vector3 (x * hexWidth, y + (0.5f * Mathf.Abs (x) % 1), 0),
                                        Quaternion.Euler (-90, 0, 0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you point out the line you get this on?

Comment: `for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight + 1; y++)` - that doesn't look right to me... why the `+ 1`? Do you *actually* want `mapHeight` elements, or `mapHeight + 1` elements?

Comment: I tried that as well the +1s were an error xD

Comment: I figured out my problem xD +1s and changing my if statement for the borders xD

Comment: I figured out the error is was indeed the +1s but I also had to change some of the if statement for the border.

Comment: if you want draw border around map, you need add `2` to map `width` and `height`, so your init should be like `new GameObject [mapHeight+2]` and `new GameObject [mapWidth+2]`